# Protect certain files from being modified or deleted

Tags: linux

I'm trying to expand my knowledge of Linux security and one thing I'm looking for is protecting select directories and files from modification, deletion, or alteration of attributes. I understand that a directory/file "owned" by `root` cannot be effected on by any non-root user. This is not enough!

My desire is to make it so that certain files and directories are write-protected and immune to the machinations of any and all users, including `root`. I've read that grsecurity and AppArmor can be used to restrict `root`, but the information has always been vague. Are either of those two able to achieve what I want or are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the similar scenario I have moved by files to a separate partition and made it read-only so no one can delete that directly. You need to have the root access and need to remount that partition to modify those files. Its the easiest way to protect those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "chattr" command to set the "immutable" attribute on the file, which is
supported by many versions of the ext(n) file system drivers. Of course,
root can always remove the attribute, but cannot otherwise modify the file in any
normal fashion.